# How to verify if a file exists in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to create a `.BAT` file that does this:

1. If `C:\myprogram\sync\data.handler` exists, exit;
2. If `C:\myprogram\html\data.sql` does not exist, exit;
3. In `C:\myprogram\sync\` delete all files and folders except (`test`, `test3` and `test2`)
4. Copy `C:\myprogram\html\data.sql` to `C:\myprogram\sync\`
5. Call other batch file with option `sync.bat myprogram.ini`.

If it was in the Bash environment it was easy for me, but I do not know how to test if a file or folder exists and if it is a file or folder.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

You can use IF EXIST to check for a file:

```
IF EXIST "filename" (
  REM Do one thing
) ELSE (
  REM Do another thing
)
```

If you do not need an "else", you can do something like this:

```
set __myVariable=
IF EXIST "C:\folder with space\myfile.txt" set __myVariable=C:\folder with space\myfile.txt
IF EXIST "C:\some other folder with space\myfile.txt" set __myVariable=C:\some other folder with space\myfile.txt
set __myVariable=
```

Here's a working example of searching for a file or a folder:

```
REM setup

echo "some text" > filename
mkdir "foldername"

REM finds file   

REM "The ELSE clause must occur on the same line
as the command after the IF"

IF EXIST "filename" (
  ECHO file filename exists
) ELSE (
  ECHO file filename does not exist
)

REM does not find file

IF EXIST "filename2.txt" (
  ECHO file filename2.txt exists
) ELSE (
  ECHO file filename2.txt does not exist
)

REM folders must have a trailing backslash    
  
REM finds folder

IF EXIST "foldername\" (
  ECHO folder foldername exists
) ELSE (
  ECHO folder foldername does not exist
)

REM does not find folder

IF EXIST "filename\" (
  ECHO folder filename exists
) ELSE (
  ECHO folder filename does not exist
)
```

Comment: How does one check full path with filename?  Bonus points if the path contains spaces.  Like OP said, simple in BASH.

Comment: @Nick: Simple in `cmd` too - please ask as a different question - they don't cost much. Adding a further question comment to one that is more than 3 years old isn't likely to garner many responses (but check SO first for answers to this precise question, else you'll get your new question marked as a duplicate...)

Comment: Just something to note from the `IF /?` help file:  
`The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.` This burned me. hope it helps you.

Comment: From an edit - _"Also note that EXIST does return true on words reserved for devices, like NUL, CON, AUX, PRN for example, even though one wouldn't technically consider them filenames."_

Comment: Reminder: IF, EXIST, ELSE, REM, DEL, etc. all work in lowercase as well!

Comment: @Nick path containing spaces needs to be put in variables, then use them like: `SET PathHavingSpace="file path"
SET SolutionDir=%PathHavingSpace%`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I follow strictly as answer suggests.

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming sorry to hear that. Perhaps you should ask a new question, showing what you have tried?

Comment: @stuartd for me if I create a simple batch file test.bat and put the code that was provided in the answer, the console simply outputs the entire code back without actual verification if the file exists or not.....

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming I expanded the answer with a working example.

Comment: to check if file not exist, use `If Not Exist "%FilePath% ( command )`. Note that, bat uses braces `(` instead of curly braces `{`

Comment: @funkymushroom You are still the real MVP in 2023. Thanks for that helpful insight and reading the manual. I was banging my head.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a good example on how to do a command if a file does or does not exist:

```
if exist C:\myprogram\sync\data.handler echo Now Exiting && Exit
if not exist C:\myprogram\html\data.sql Exit
```

We will take those three files and put it in a temporary place. After deleting the folder, it will restore those three files.

```
xcopy "test" "C:\temp"
xcopy "test2" "C:\temp"
del C:\myprogram\sync\
xcopy "C:\temp" "test"
xcopy "C:\temp" "test2"
del "c:\temp"
```

Use the [XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) command:

```
xcopy "C:\myprogram\html\data.sql"  /c /d /h /e /i /y  "C:\myprogram\sync\"
```

I will explain what the `/c /d /h /e /i /y` means:

```
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
  /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
               If no date is given, copies only those files whose
               source time is newer than the destination time.
  /H           Copies hidden and system files also.
  /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
               Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
  /T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
               include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes
  /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
               assumes that destination must be a directory.
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.

`To see all the commands type`xcopy /? in cmd
```

> Call other batch file with option sync.bat myprogram.ini.

I am not sure what you mean by this, but if you just want to open both of these files you just put the path of the file like

```
Path/sync.bat
Path/myprogram.ini
```

> If it was in the Bash environment it was easy for me, but I do not
>   know how to test if a file or folder exists and if it is a file or
>   folder.

You are using a batch file. You mentioned earlier you have to create a .bat file to use this:

> I have to create a .BAT file that does this:

Answer (score 13):

Type IF /? to get help about if, it clearly explains how to use IF EXIST.

To delete a complete tree except some folders, see the answer of this question: [Windows batch script to delete everything in a folder except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008567/windows-batch-script-to-delete-everything-in-a-folder-except-one/3009151)

Finally copying just means calling COPY and calling another bat file can be done like this:

```
MYOTHERBATFILE.BAT sync.bat myprogram.ini
```