# Remove file name prefix with cmd

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have thousands of files in one folder and most of them have prefix in name like this: NNNN_*.jpg

For example **3453_dfgdhfdgh.jpg**, **1000_dfgdhfdgh.jpg**, **5463_dfgdhfdgh.jpg** etc.

How can I with CMD rename all files by remove prefix in files, in which such prefix exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always a four-digit number in the front, then that's rather easy:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "FN=%%F"
  set "FN=!FN:~5!"
  ren "%%F" "!FN!"
)
goto :eof
```

But maybe you need to check first whether that's really true, in which case we need two helper functions (add them below the part above):

```
:IsDigit
set Digit=
if "%~1" GEQ "0" if "%~1" LEQ "9" set Digit=1
goto :eof

:IsNumber
setlocal
set "File=%~1"
set Number=
call :IsDigit "%File:~0,1%"
set Digit1=%Digit%
call :IsDigit "%File:~1,1%"
set Digit2=%Digit%
call :IsDigit "%File:~2,1%"
set Digit3=%Digit%
call :IsDigit "%File:~3,1%"
set Digit4=%Digit%
if "%Digit1%%Digit2%%Digit3%%Digit4%"=="1111" set Number=1
endlocal & set Number=%Number%
goto :eof
```

and then adapt as follows:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "FN=%%F"
  call :IsNumber "!FN!"
  if defined Number if "!FN:~4,1!"=="_" (
    set "FN=!FN:~5!"
    ren "%%F" "!FN!"
  )
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: The only problem is `1000_a.jpg` will be overwritten by `1001_a.jpg`?

Comment: Well, yes. You should have a rough idea what to do with duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, it's seems not working. Created .bat file with your code

Comment: CMD gives me an error: 'D:\photos\standard>(
set "FN=2433_11e5b546228f8753773320f950651b29f.jpg"
 set "FN=!FN:~5,!"
 ren "2433_11e5b546228f8753773320f950651b29f.jpg" "!FN!"
)
File with such name already exists'

Comment: Check if it already exists before you rename: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file

Comment: I have only one file for test in folder **2433_11e5b546228f8753773320f950651b29f.jpg**

Comment: Ok, I had two bugs in that code (I didn't test when I was writing it). There still remains the problem with duplicates but that's something you should know how to handle. You can overwrite the files, try appending a unique counter, leave those alone that would clash, ... there are various possibilities but I don't know what you need.

Comment: With echo I found that set "FN=!FN:~5,!" gives me empty string.. That's it gives me error

Comment: I already fixed that; that was one of the two bugs I was mentioning.