# Batch Script Optimization

Tags: batch-file

I am working on some batch script with following code block:

```
echo off 
echo SETTING UP ANT FOR THE BUILD ....
set ANT_HOME=%~dp0%build\apache-ant-1.8.2
set ANT_BIN=%~dp0%build\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin

SET path=%path%;%ANT_BIN%;%ANT_BIN%;

echo PATH: %path%
echo ANT_HOME: %ANT_HOME%
echo ANT_BIN: %ANT_BIN%
echo ANT GOT INSTALLED ....
```

It help me to set up my path to my ant path in environment variable.

Now, each time i run this bat file it goes for setting up the environment variable for ant.

I have to put some condition that if path is already there then just skip the setup option else setup option begins.

How can we do this using bat script? As i am new to bat script i tried with following code block:

IF "%ANT_HOME%" == "" GOTO NOPATH
:YESPATH
...

:NOPATH
...

but the problem here is i am not able to get how to check the case for following:
The %ANT_HOME% is not blank but have some invalid ant directory path.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if a file exists in a Windows .BAT file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in your script:

```
SET path=%path%;%ANT_BIN%;%ANT_BIN%;
```

this should be:

```
SET "path=%path%;%ANT_HOME%;%ANT_BIN%"
```

if you want to check for a not existing path you should place a backslash at the end. Otherwise this is also true, if a file with this name exists:

```
if exist "%ANT_HOME%\" (echo %ANT_HOME% found.) else echo Error: %ANT_HOME% not found!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF EXIST` to check if a file exists. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340395/492336):

```
if exist "%ANT_HOME%" (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid, adding your entries multiple times to the path, you should check this.

```
set path | find "%ANT_HOME%;%ANT_BIN%"
```

will give you %errorlevel% of '0' when it is already appended,or '1' when not.

Comment: Anyway: %path% is removed at the end of a cmd session, if not stored in the registry.