# If/Else In Batch File

Tags: batch-file

**Syntax for batch File for IF then ELSE**

How to create batch File which can check if file exists then exit out else create new file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if a file exists in a Windows .BAT file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file)

Comment: We always strive to write correct syntax, no need to include it in the question. It also makes an otherwise valid question look like a "give me teh codez" type question (which it sort of is, but there are worse).

Comment: It would help if you had some relevant code that you have tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
@echo off
set "$file=the_file.txt"
if exist %$file% (exit) else (echo new>%$file%)
```