# How do you specify a folder path in batch?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

In Batch, I know you can always specify a folder path in batch/cmd, for example,

```
echo %RANDOM% >> C:\Users\User\Logs\log.txt
```

or

```
start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

But what if for example, your batch file was used in a product, where these locations may differ or not exist? How would you specify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if a file exists in a Windows .BAT file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file)

Comment: I suspect you may want `%~dp0` - the path to the batch file that is currently executing.

Comment: There are variables (often referred to as "environment variables") that Windows creates to help you find certain things.  You can see a list of them by type `set` at a cmd prompt.  So if you want to launch a program from the windows directory, but you aren't sure that windows directory is "c:\windows", you can use `start %windir%\system32\cmd.exe`.  Similarly, there is USERPROFILE, so you can do echo %random% > %USERPROFILE%\logs\log.txt.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist filename.ext (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Please also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file).

If that is not possible to use relative path, use environment variables; because every thing can be different in your client station.