# how to detect the existence of a txt file using a batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to write a batch script to run on windows.

I will schedule that file to run every minute on the server to test the existence of a txt file, on that server and then delete it.

Wha the batch file does is this:

check the existence of txt file on the server and if it finds that file in that location, 1) delete it 2 ) run some other actions.

I know what those actions are. I got the code for it already.

I need help only on how to check the existence of that txt file and how to delete it if it is there.

What commands do I need?

I'd appreciate if you could throw some pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify if a file exists in a Windows .BAT file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file)

Answer (score 0):

Rob Van Der Woude's batch file reference is an excellent source:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php
As it examples show how this can be achieved.

```
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
```

Something like this...

```
IF EXIST file.txt Start script.bat
```

Or...

```
IF EXIST file.txt GOTO somelabel
```