# How remove all files and folders in the folder except one folder in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have problem. I need remove files except one folder. Then create folder and copy files in folder. I used this script:

```
rd /s /q %1
mkdir %1
xcopy /s /i %2\* %1
```

But it deleted all files. How I can rewrite this script?

Comment: move what you wish to keep elsewhere; remove everything that remains, move the first item back here

Comment: I have folder in jenkins. I need move files from jenkins to iis.

Comment: but in iis there is other sites which i can't delete

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3008567/2152082)?